# File exists in docker run volume but not docker-compose volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, certificate, docker-volume

I'm trying to figure out why I can find a certificate file in a volume using:

```
docker run -v ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro -p 80:80 -p 443:433 -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=<MY PASSWORD HERE> housesearchwebsite
```

but not using:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.custom.yml up
```

with a docker-compose.custom.yml that looks like this: (sensitive information removed)

```
version: '3.4'

services:   
  housesearchwebsite:
    image: housesearchwebsite
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ConnectionString=host=db;port=5432;database=<DATABASENAME>;username=<DBUSERNAME>password=<MY DB PASSWORD>
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=<MY PASSWORD HERE>
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    ports:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    volumes:
      - ${HOME}/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
      - images_volume:/var/lib/housesearch/images
    networks:
      - dev-net

volumes:
  images_volume:

networks:
  dev-net:
    name: dev-net
```

I have some C# code that checks, first thing, if there is a aspnetapp.pfx file in the `ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path` path, but it is only found if I run the docker run command, and is not found if I use the docker-compose command.

Comment: For some reason it just started working.. Maybe because I added the linux user to the docker group?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it started working randomly, but an issue I can clearly flag which might have been the reason for your error is that you are not mapping the ports properly in your `docker-compose.yml`.

Ports should be defined as:

```yaml
ports:
 - "80:80"
 - "443:443"
```

Where the mapping would be in `HOST:CONTAINER` format.

Docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ports)

Comment: But from the link you posted: [...]There are three options:[...]"Specify both ports (HOST:CONTAINER)" [...or...] "Specify just the container port (an ephemeral host port is chosen for the host port)." [...]
Doesn't that mean that it would work fine to just put a single number for each? I realize it might be good practice though.

Comment: That's correct, but you can't make the assumption the host port is going to be the same when using that syntax as that gets allocated automatically; That could cause problems like in your case, where you set your environment with static ports (`ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80`)

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for explaining it!